# Identify what parcels would be protected by seawalls

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, spatial-join, overlapping-features

I have a shapefile for land parcels near the coast. I have a shapefile with polylines that represent seawalls. Here is what I would like to do:

1. Spatial join seawalls with my parcels data. This is easy enough to do.
2. Identify neighboring parcels that are potentially protected by seawalls as well. Say an arbitrary distance like 20m. But this search has to be behind the seawall and not inside a circular radius. So in the image I attach with the two blue "X", the one on the left would be protected by seawall(Green Line) and all properties 20m behind it within the red lines would also be protected. The "X" on the right falls within 20m of a protected property, but is not actually protected because it is not behind a seawall.

[image]

3. Lastly, each seawall line has a distance attribute to it.

Is there a way to calculate what distance is overlapped with each parcel?

Comment: What software are you using? Do the lines actually touch the parcels or are they offset into the sea slightly?

Comment: @TeddyTedTed I am using Arcgis pro. The seawalls touch the parcel.

Comment: You can use the generate near table tool as it can return angle, then just filter on data that is approximately perpendicular to the sea wall.

Comment: A 20m buffer with a "flat" end (rather than a round end) looks like it would work, you'd also have to crop to the land polygon to cut out the bit of buffer over the seaward-side of the walls....